# Запятая или тире при уточнении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, уточнения

*Рассказ о "короле" музыкальных инструментов — органе.*

Почему-то хочется поставить здесь тире, хотя по правилам вроде бы нужна запятая. Есть ли случаи, когда нужно все-таки тире, если это не середина предложения?

Answer (score 2):

***Тире перед приложением Вы поставили правильно.***

При обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:

1) если перед приложением можно вставить слова а именно (без изменения смысла): *В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.); Она зарисовала древние светильники с гербом города Ольвии — орлом, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.); На суховатом лице Нечаева, с мягким мальчишеским лбом, остались следы ожогов — два белых незагорающих пятна (Н. Чук.);*

2) перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение:*Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину* (Т.) [Д.Э.Розенталь. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения!

Comment: @Татьяна  Благодарность — на сайте — отображается нажатием кнопки-стрелки «Ответ полезен».